# JavaScript RegExp matching group takes unwanted parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I got text like: **do[A]and[B]**

I want to extract all words that are wrapped by <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>.
I am using the *match* method:

```
var text = "do[A]and[B]";
var regexp = /\[(\w+)\]/g;
var result = text.match(regexp);
```

So I am saying that I want to match all words wrapped by [ ], but only the wrapped part should be in group/memory. I keep getting the [ ] parentheses in result:

```
["[A]", "[B]"]
```

**expected result is**:

```
["A","B"]
```

I thought this is a piece of cake to do, but I must be missing something.

Comment: @Barmar: thanks, sometimes it's hard to find correct search keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with subpatterns, there is no easy shortcut.

Instead, you have to repeatedly execute the regex on the string and collect the subpattern you want. Something like this:

```
var text = "do[A]and[B]",
    regexp = /\[(\w+)\]/g,
    result = [], match;
while(match = regexp.exec(text)) {
    result.push(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: Well this is disappointing - from JS, not you :) Thanks for the answer, I'll try it this way.

Comment: If JS had lookbehinds, you could just do `/(?<\[)\w+(?=\])/g`, but sadly it does not.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular case you don't need capturing groups:

```
>>> "do[A]and[Bbbb]".match(/\w+(?=])/g);
["A", "Bbbb"]
```

will do.